# elasticsearch 2.0 parent child grandchild

Tags: elasticsearch, parent, elasticsearch-2.0

My operation:

parent: country, child: branch, grandchild: employee

> PUT /company {   "mappings": {
>       "branch": {
>         "_parent": {
>           "type": "country" 
>         }
>       },
>       "employee": {
>         "_parent": {
>           "type": "branch" 
>         }
>       }   } }

I want add a grandchild employee2, parent is branch:

> PUT /company/employee2/_mapping {   "employee2": {
>       "_parent": {
>         "type": "branch"
>       }   } }

I get wrong message:

> {    "error": {
>         "root_cause": [
>            {
>               "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
>               "reason": "can't add a _parent field that points to an already existing type"
>            }
>         ],
>         "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
>         "reason": "can't add a _parent field that points to an already existing type"    },    "status": 400 }

I don't know how can i do. Have any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a restriction imposed in elasticsearch 2.0. 
This is mentioned in [breaking changes in 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_parent_child_changes.html#_parent_type_cannot_pre_exist). However the reason behind this this is not clear in the document.

Below is what  martijnvg an elasticsearch developer posted on elasticsearch discuss threads:

> a new child type can't point to an existing type as parent.
>
> This has to do with the fact that with the new parent/child
>   implementation both parent and child types store ids in a join field.
>   If type becomes a parent after it has been created then parent
>   documents may have been indexed that didn't store their id in the join
>   field. For this reason this restriction exists.
>
> This only applies for new indices created after the upgrade to ES 2.0.
>   For migration purposes this restriction doesn't apply for indices
>   created before the upgrade to ES 2.0. In fact on created on ES 1.x and
>   before the old parent/child implementation is being used.

You can read about it here :
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/adding-child-types-in-2-0/33267

Answer (score 0):

Ok
I have found the problem - you cannot create parent-child relation with an existing type
after deleting the index all was fine