# Spring Data Elasticsearch Parent/Child Document Repositories / Test execution error

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I created two Spring-Data elasticsearch repositories for two parent/child related documents. You can see the document classes for both of them [here](https://github.com/ltsallas/spring-data-elastic-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/domain/ParentEntity.java).

The repositories are getting instantiated in XML with the help of repositories element like this

```
<elasticsearch:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />
```

You can find a complete example of the issue in [this](https://github.com/ltsallas/spring-data-elastic-test) github repo. My source code is based in the tests found in [spring-data-elasticsearch repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch). The source code consists of just two domain classes(parent,child), the related repositories, the xml configuration files and a [unit test class](https://github.com/ltsallas/spring-data-elastic-test/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/DemoApplicationTests.java).

Clone and run `mvn test`, throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't add a _parent field that points to an already existing type, that isn't already a parent`

It seems that this parent/child relationship produces an elastic search exception which is clear in the [Elasticsearch side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670057/elasticsearch-2-0-parent-child-grandchild/), but I do not know how to prevent this from happening when executing the Spring Data test.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for the answer I solved this by Setting the createIndex=false in the @Document of the parent. 
And creating this in manually in the beans

```
            elasticSearchTemplate.createIndex(Parent.class);
            elasticSearchTemplate.putMapping(parent.class);
            elasticSearchTemplate.createIndex(Child1.class);
            elasticSearchTemplate.createIndex(Child2.class);
```

This should create the parent first and then the associated children. 
Also do clear the document before you update the mapping.